# C# ASP.net Visual Studio application remove file build failure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have a C# ASP.net project which is in source control in TFS 2012 express.

A team member removed a file and remove all references to it called overview.aspx - and his project built fine.

He delivered changes and I received the latest version.

Now when I try to build I get the following error:

```
Error reading file <path to file>/overview.resources - the system cannot find the file specific File: CSC
```

I then right clicked the overview.aspx file and clicked remove - followed by a clean on the project, a rebuild and build - both of the builds failing with the error above.

Can somebody please explain what reference to this file still exists and how I can remove it from the project.

Comment: If you open the project file in a text editor, is there any reference to the file?

Comment: There was, I removed that and it worked. So is there a way to make sure the project file is kept in sync because obviously that is not being committed when changes occur on either end?

Comment: The project file should be checked in to source control like any other.  It's part of the codebase used to build the resulting application(s).  If the team is making changes to the project and not checking in those changes, the problem isn't in the project file...

Comment: Turned out it was - had simply not been committed as part of the changeset.